# java.io.FileNotFoundException Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a problem when run my project in eclipse

my code :

```
public class knn {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        System.out.println("iris");
        knn("classification\\iris_train.txt","classification\\iris_test.txt",1,2);
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("glass");
        knn("classification\\glass_train.txt","classification\\glass_test.txt",1,0);
        System.out.println();
```

the error message :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: classification\iris_train.txt (Le
>   chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)

pic of the project :
[image]

Comment: The posted code is clearly not your real code (or at least not enough of it), as you're trying to use a class name as a static method. Do you have a static `knn` method? What does it look like? Separately, where is the `classification` directory relative to the current directory configured when you run the project?

Comment: Do you need to go up a directory? `"..\\classification\\glass_train.txt"`

Comment: Please also post the code of the knn method.

Comment: classification looks like to be a package than folder....why are you doing that?

Comment: classification is a folder contain txt files

Comment: The “current directory” and relative filenames are fundamental concepts of most operating systems.  You should become familiar with them before writing programs that deal with files.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not know where the text file is "classification\iris_train.txt"
you will need to give it a better path than just classification. What is the exact path of the  "iris_train.txt" file?

[Folder vs Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm5T0.png)

Comment: i put it in the project ( look at the picture )

Comment: it should be on comment.

Comment: Can you try to create a new folder call classifications, i agree with sanket. the classifications "folder" is not a folder since the tick tack looking box is a package symbol. The folders symbol looks like a generic windows folder. Also i was asking if you could post the expanded classifications section. Folders should show up below your referenced library section.